# Word addin template fails to open a document created on 32bit env in a 64bit env

Tags: ms-word, vsto, .net-4.5, office-addins

I have a word addin x86, so in windows 32bit it is installed on "Programs File" while on 64bit windows in "Programs File (x86)". The problem is that when I open a document created with a 32bit version of the addin on a 64bit environment the system arise an error. Office try to search the template.vsto on "Programs file" but the correct path is "Programs File (x86)". I have put a lot of break point in the code but I'm not able to understand the exact line of code where the exception arise. Is there a way to debug all project lines, line by line automatically?
Any suggestions? 
I use Visual Studio 2013 and the add in is for office 2013.
EDIT: the addin allow the user to create document using only styles allowed by the word template.

[image: dialog that appear when an user open a document]

Comment: You use the term "add-in", but this sounds to be like a document-level customization? That's a very important difference... And how is the project published/deployed? Click-Once, or something else?

Comment: The project is an add in for Microsoft Office Word that use a word template, it is deployed using a .msi installer. When you try to import using the add in, a document that was created on windows 64 bit on a windows 32 bit it raise the error in the screenshot. I'm not able to understand where the exception is raised. When you import a document created with the 64bit on 32bit it try to search the vsto in the wrong folder.

Comment: Does the add-in work with the x64-Version of Office? And does everything work, if the source document has been created with a 64-bit Office version?